# Storing Stripe Checkout Session ID in $_SESSION and checking on Success

Tags: php, session, stripe-payments

I am Storing Stripe Checkout Session ID in $_SESSION and checking on Success.php if the $_GET['session_id'] matches the $_SESSION['checkout_id'] I created at checkout but it's not always matching.

Am i approaching this right? For some reason it never fails on my local machine but only on the production CPanel instance.

CreateCheckoutSession.php snippet:

```
$_SESSION['checkout_id'] = "";
    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => $line_items,
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/checkout/success.php?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&php_session_id='.$session_id.'',
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/checkout/canceled.php?php_session_id='.$session_id.'',
]);
    $_SESSION['checkout_id'] = $checkout_session->id;
```

success.php snippet:

```
<?php

session_start();
$session_id=session_id();
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
//Load Composer's autoloader
require '../php/vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
//wipe basket if not already
include_once("../php/connect.php");
//check basket exists




//if ($_SESSION['checkout_id'] != $_GET['session_id']) {
if ($_SESSION['checkout_id'] != $_GET['session_id']) {

    //echo $_SESSION['checkout_id'];
    //echo $session_id;
    //echo $_GET['php_session_id'];
    
    //echo $_GET['session_id'];
    //header('Location: ../index.php');
```

Error Message:
Warning: Undefined array key "checkout_id" in home/public_html/checkout/success.php on line 21

Redirect URL Example:
success.php?session_id=cs_test_a1zoOWt5bwr7t3xtk67waAbS9Q7xyDp6GlLbuneNnfmp7SC4XaJWI4CgWD&php_session_id=fa3b43e0b3a5e2da9485ae1f6c97a1b0

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to check that these two match? Do both `$_GET['session_id']` and `$_SESSION['checkout_id']` look like valid Stripe Checkout Session IDs that don't match, or is the issue that one is empty/not even a valid ID?

Comment: @karbi I'm checking they match to avoid an unlikely scneario inwhich someone could just go to success.php and it show there order as completed in my database. I could just not check thats what I'm doing to test, but I don't understand why sometimes they match and sometimes they don't i never encountered this ion the local server. I just tested and it is saying checkout id is not defined. But it is assigned at the time the checkoutsession is created same as in local env

  Warning: Undefined array key "checkout_id"

Comment: @karbi added some code snippets if anything stands out as an error

Comment: First thing you should check, is whether your session got picked up again correctly in these cases. Check what the session ID is before you send the user to the checkout, and after they return from there.

Comment: @CBroe I am sending the php session as an additional parameter. Why would the session change on the php side though its still the same browser session it seems bizzare

Comment: _"I am sending the php session as an additional parameter."_ - and you have PHP instructed to pick it up from there? (Default these days is to use cookies only.) _"Why would the session change on the php side though its still the same browser session it seems bizzare"_ - if you were using cookies, then `SameSite` can come into play.

Answer (score 0):

The session context was being lost, Shout out to @CBroe

I had to get the session context and re set it on the occasions it was losing context. I also didn't neeed to be verifying the stripe tokens.

```
if ($real_session_id != $php_session_id){
    session_destroy();
    session_id($php_session_id);
    session_start();
}
```